Пытаюсь получить параметр FileIndex для папки, но не выходит
Работаю с функцией GetFileInformationByHandleEx(), в неё можно передать структуру FILE_FULL_DIR_INFO которая должна дать информацию о директории. Мне нужны только данные из поля FileIndex, но в итоге получаю NULL, хотя там должно лежать кол-во секторов (работаю с файловой системой FAT. Подробно объяснять не буду, поскольку через HEX редактор проверил что данные там имеются);
Источник: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex
Код, который не работает, как мне нужно:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
    L"J:\\Новая папка",               
    GENERIC_READ,                          
    FILE_SHARE_READ,                      
    NULL,                                 
    OPEN_EXISTING,                       
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,                
    NULL                                 
);



//BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileInfo;
//FILE_FULL_DIR_INFO fileInfo;
//FILE_ID_INFO fileInfo;                          //FileIdInfo
_FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO fileInfo;                  //FileIdBothDirectoryInfo 


if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileIdBothDirectoryInfo, &fileInfo,
    sizeof(_FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO)))
{
    DWORD index = fileInfo.FileIndex;

}
else std::cout << GetLastError();

CloseHandle(hFile);

return 0;

З.Ы Как-то случайно, когда тыкал эту функцию, я как-то получил эти значения, удивился, поскольку получилось случайно и забыл как это делается, даже не сохранил. Точно помню что сделать это можно. Помогите, пожалуйста, уже неделю долблюсь с этой задачей, а костыль применять не хочется для проекта, ибо он там очень большой...
